# Does writing a large CSV stream to an in-memory ZipOutputStream consumes as much memory as the size of the CSV or of the potential zip?

Tags: java, zip

I have Zip containing a large CSV. (hence its zipped) 
I want to add one column to the CSV and zip it again.

I am okay with having the entire Zip in memory but definitely not the whole CSV. So if I write the CSV chunk by chunk to a particular ZipEntry of the ZipOutputStream (in-memory). Will it take up entire space in heap as the CSV data would nee or would take as much as the Zip file would need?

Comment: Just try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how we would tyipically copy from zip to zip:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((currentEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(currentEntry.getName());
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(newEntry);
            int length;
            while ((length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();                   
        }
```

from this code we can assume that the program will read / write in chunks by 8k